# How to send as form data angular

Tags: angular

I had made one http.post() With the datas for the payment gataway,But the response is the template of the payment page.I have conact them and told me to send the datas as a formdata .how can i send this as form data?

**payment.ts**

```
 var paymentdata={
  'api_key':'6953gbfa-939a-4bd8-927c-fdsdd6e0fa72f',
  'order_id':'11111111111124',
  'mode':'TEST', 
  'amount':200,
  'currency':'INR',
  'description':'BLABLA',
  'name':'Ajith',
  'email':'ajith@gmail.com',
  'phone':'8086502009',
  'city':'tvm',
  'country':'IND',
  'zip_code':'695505',
  'return_url':'http://localhost:8100/#/payment/paymentrequest',
  'hash':'8A9DBABCF0CBB9618F74DEA95982DD5D710347B643F45A1E1DFF
   A42941EACB77C9F8D5C79F7D2EF8fdfDDFCD944E7EDE36F5D2FF8FBC5D0
   822A2C79CBDCE73DE05' 
   }
  console.log(paymentdata)
  return 
 this.http.post('https://biz.traknpay.in/v2/paymentrequest',paymentdata).
 map(res=>res).subscribe(res=>
 {
  this.body=res.text();
  console.log(this.body)
  },
err=>{
 console.log(err)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let paymentData = new FormData();

paymentData.append('api_key', '6953gbfa-939a-4bd8-927c-fdsdd6e0fa72f');
paymentData.append('order_id', '11111111111124);
.
.
.
//add all the data the same way

return http.post('url', paymentData,...);
```

technically, just use a FormData object instead of the array.